# how to handle string indexer and onehot encoder in pyspark pipeline stages

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, pipeline

Facing this error for this code:

```
stage_string = [StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol=c + "_string_encoded")  for c in categorical_columns]
stage_one_hot = [OneHotEncoder(inputCol=c + "_string_encoded", outputCol=c + "_one_hot") for c in categorical_columns]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_list, outputCol="features")
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="output", featuresCol="features")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[stage_string,stage_one_hot,assembler, rf]) 
pipeline.fit(df)
```

```
Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <class 'list'>.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line 132, in fit
    return self._fit(dataset)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 97, in _fit
    "Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type %s." % type(stage))
TypeError: Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <class 'list'>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with this **`pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[stage_string,stage_one_hot,assembler, rf])`** statement `stage_string` and `stage_one_hot` are the lists of `PipelineStage` and `assembler` and rf is individual pipelinestage.

Modify your statement as below-

```
stages = stage_string + stage_one_hot + [assembler, rf]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
```